# Generate $_POST variables automaticly

Tags: php, sql

Im building an extensive form for calculations, im building it in a way that it is automatized, so the inputs are generated from the database having their name as something like this a count in a while loop

```
<input type="text" placeholder="0" value="0" name="a_'.$count.'" />
```

This part works fine the thing is that im trying to generate the variables for the $_POST this is what i currently have and for sure it's not correct.

```
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 119; ++$i) {


        ${"a_$i"} = htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($_POST['a_'.$i]));


    }
```

after this ill build the sql to insert in db which i already have, only this part is missing.

EDIT :

After trying adding to an array , i know get this message when inserting :

Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /home/gmtemhic/urbanos.gm-tests.xyz/modules/form_particular/view/form_particular.tpl.php on line 261

```
if($insert = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO request_form_particular(nome,email,tel,morada_origem,codigopostal,morada_destino,codigopostal_destino,dataprevista,mensagem,a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, a_8, a_9, a_10, a_11, a_12, a_13, a_14, a_15, a_16, a_17, a_18, a_19, a_20, a_21, a_22, a_23, a_24, a_25, a_26, a_27, a_28, a_29, a_30, a_31, a_32, a_33, a_34, a_35, a_36, a_37, a_38, a_39, a_40, a_41, a_42, a_43, a_44, a_45, a_46, a_47, a_48, a_49, a_50, a_51, a_52, a_53, a_54, a_55, a_56, a_57, a_58, a_59, a_60, a_61, a_62, a_63, a_64, a_65, a_66, a_67, a_68, a_69, a_70, a_71, a_72, a_73, a_74, a_75, a_76, a_77, a_78, a_79, a_80, a_81, a_82, a_83, a_84, a_85, a_86, a_87, a_88, a_89, a_90, a_91, a_92, a_93, a_94, a_95, a_96, a_97, a_98, a_99, a_100, a_101, a_102, a_103, a_104, a_105, a_106, a_107, a_108, a_109, a_110, a_111, a_112, a_113, a_114, a_115, a_116, a_117, a_118, a_119) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")){
        $insert->bind_param("ssissssssiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii",
        $nome,$email,$tel,$morada_origem,$codigopostal,$morada_destino,$codigopostal_destino,$dataprevista,$mensagem,$values[0],$values[1],$values[2],$values[3],$values[4],$values[5],$values[6],$values[7],$values[8],$values[9],$values[10],$values[11],$values[12],$values[13],$values[14],$values[15],$values[16],$values[17],$values[18],$values[19],$values[20],$values[21],$values[22],$values[23],$values[24],$values[25],$values[26],$values[27],$values[28],$values[29],$values[30],$values[31],$values[32],$values[33],$values[34],$values[35],$values[36],$values[37],$values[38],$values[39],$values[40],$values[41],$values[42],$values[43],$values[44],$values[45],$values[46],$values[47],$values[48],$values[49],$values[50],$values[51],$values[52],$values[53],$values[54],$values[55],$values[56],$values[57],$values[58],$values[59],$values[60],$values[61],$values[62],$values[63],$values[64],$values[65],$values[66],$values[67],$values[68],$values[69],$values[70],$values[71],$values[72],$values[73],$values[74],$values[75],$values[76],$values[77],$values[78],$values[79],$values[80],$values[81],$values[82],$values[83],$values[84],$values[85],$values[86],$values[87],$values[88],$values[89],$values[90],$values[91],$values[92],$values[93],$values[94],$values[95],$values[96],$values[97],$values[98],$values[99],$values[100],$values[101],$values[102],$values[103],$values[104],$values[105],$values[106],$values[107],$values[108],$values[109],$values[110],$values[111],$values[112],$values[113],$values[114],$values[115],$values[116],$values[117],$values[118]);
        $insert->execute();
        echo "DONE";
        }else{
            echo "Error :".$connect->error;
        }
```

Comment: Why not push them in to an array?

Comment: foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {...}

Comment: You can use an array to store the elements either using a numeric value (`$i`) or a name (`a_$i`) to identify the value in the array. Check my answer for more details.

Comment: Sidenote: What you're doing there with `real_escape_string` and *then* `htmlentities` is definitely wrong. But since I don't know what it's supposed to do, I can't tell you what you should do instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using an array to store the $_POST values for example:

```
$values = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= 119; $i++) {
    $values[$i] = htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($_POST["a_{$i}"]));
}
```

Or if you prefer to use the names of the elements as indexes in the array:

$values = array();

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 119; $i++) {
    $values["a_{$i}"] = htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($_POST["a_{$i}"]));
}
```

And then reference each element in the array as follows (`$index` will either be the position of the element `$i` or the name of the element `a_$i` depending on the method you use:

```
foreach ($values as $index=>$value) {
    // Perform your actions here
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

With relations to adding the values to the database, based on your method, what you can do is the following:

- Create an array (`$additional_fields`) which will store the name of each field. You can either use a for loop from `0 - 119` as you did before and place the `a_$i` values in the array or as shown below if all fields will be completed.
- Create another array (`$values_list`) which will store only the values to be inserted into the database.
- And the last array (`$values_identifiers`) will just be a placeholder (`?`) for each value.

The code is as follows:

```
$additional_fields = array();
$values_list = array($nome, $email, $tel, $morada_origem, $codigopostal, $morada_destino, $codigopostal_destino, $dataprevista, $mensagem);
$values_identifiers = array();

foreach ($values $key=>$value) {
    $additional_fields[] = $key;
    $values_list[] = $value;
    $values_identifiers[] = '?';
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO request_form_particular (nome, email, tel, morada_origem, codigopostal, morada_destino, codigopostal_destino, dataprevista, mensagem, ".implode(', ', $additional_fields).' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '.implode(', ', $values_identifiers).')';
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);

if ($stmt->execute($values_list)) {
    echo 'Done';
} else {
    echo 'Error: '.$connect->error;
}
```

Comment: How should i insert it ? it tells me only variables can be passed as reference

Comment: @Gongas I updated the answer. Check it and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

> extract — Import variables into the current symbol table from an array

However, take note:

> **Warning** Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. $_GET, $_FILES).

You could also make this work with [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php),

Alternatively, you could use what I suggested in my comment, that is, you loop through the `$_POST` and get the keys / values and push them in to an array.

```
$data = [];    

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, ['submit-button'])) {
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

That way you have the keys that were used in the names in `$data`.

Comment: Just as a side note: take into account that the POST/GET arrays contain everything you send including submit button values, hidden fields and even malicious or unintentionally malformed stuff etc. so the warning and best practices are always valid not only for the `extract`... you need to do some filtering/exclusions inside the loop too.

Comment: @FrancescoG. yes, you are quite right. I have updated the snippet with a simple `in_array` for the excluded keys. The OP can work on from that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_push`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp) function and `count()` function for loop length as:

```
 $dataObject = [];
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($_POST); ++$i) {
         array_push($dataObject,htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($_POST['a_'.$i])));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you can use an array as a name of your html input like this :

```
<form method="post" action="collect_vals.php">
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

and Collecting values from above input fields is pretty simple, take a look at example below:

```
echo $_POST["mytext"][0];
echo $_POST["mytext"][1];
```

have a look at this pretty [exemple](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/04/capture-array-values-from-dynamic-input-fields-using-php)